# Jackson - How to serialize javascript function

Tags: jackson

I use Jackson to generate a JSON formatted String from Java objects.

The generated JSON string is then sent in a HTTPResponse and Highcharts interprets it client-side to display a chart.

It was all fine until I found out I need to serialize a JavaScript function. E.g

```
"xAxis" : {
    events {
        setExtremes: function(event) {
            //javascript code
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware this is not valid JSON anymore but I need a workaround.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although I know nothing about jackson, I had a similar problem doing this in a java json library.

What did was put a placeholder value where I wanted the function to go:

```
setExtremes: "SETEXTREMES_PLACEHOLDER"
```

Then when I had converted the json object to a json string, I did a string replace operation on the placeholder with the required function.

Not pretty, but it did the job.

Comment: i'll accept this answer although you're right, it's not pretty.

Comment: Not sure how up to date this answer is. There's the [`@RawValue`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonRawValue.html) annotation in Jackson that will prevent the quoting of the value (for already serialized objects and functions).